# How to change radio button value into string and send to csv file?

Tags: vb.net, csv, vb.net-2010

I have a group box called grpWindows which contains three radio buttons:

rdbUnderSlabComplete,
rdbUnderSlabCurrent,
rdbUnderSlabNA

I want to get the selected value of the radio button and convert it to a string (Different string for each radio button), which will then be sent to a csv file.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried searching on the internet?

Comment: Yes but i don't understand how to apply those different situations to my own. Bare in mind im not completely sure as to what im doing.

Comment: I suggest you search for tutorials then. If you cannot adopt an existing answer to such a simple question you will likely not understand any answer given to you. I am not trying to put you down, I am suggesting that you go though a few tutorials first to get a better understanding of the language and the environment.

Comment: It's not a case of "get the selected value of the radio button". A `RadioButton` doesn't have a "selected value". There are three `RadioButtons` and no more than one of them at a time can be checked. You need to determine which of them is checked and then use that one to do whatever is appropriate in the situation. Any basic tutorial will go through `If` statements so if you don't know how to use them then you absolutely need to follow the advice provided by @Alex and read up on the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly simple and shows you should read some tutorials.

Generally you some code like this.

```
    Private Sub Rb2meter_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Rb2meter.CheckedChanged

    If Rb2meter.Checked = True Then
        FillListBox1()
    End If



End Sub
```

this is something I pulled from a project.

simply use the radio buttons event changed and perform your code.